# Magento 2.4.1 payment methods not showing in admin area

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I migrated Magento 2.3.1 to Magento 2.4.1 everything is fine except payment methods not showing in the admin panel Setting> Sales> Payment Methods See the Screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In such case I'd try:

- Making sure all the caches and generated files are cleared. Something like  `rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* && ./bin/magento c:c`
- Tailing the logs and reload the page to see if throws any errors. ex. `tail -f var/log/*.log` or `tail -f var/log/exception.log`
- Disable all the custom modules and try loading the same page
- Disable all the patches and reinstall the core modules without them all

I believe one of these steps should work and based on each case, you'll follow the route to resolve